# Javascript Regex matching strings separated by space but not containing a dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match words that are not separated by dots in a string.
Because there are no lookbehinds in Javascript I've been struggling with this and can't get it to work.

Teststring 1: `'one two three.four five six.seven eight'`
should match: `'one', 'two', 'five', 'eight'`

Teststring 2: `'one.two three four.five six seven.eight'`
should match: `'three', 'six'`

**Update:**
Teststring 3: `'one.two three four five six seven.eight'`
should match: `'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'`

So far I have `( |^)(\w+)( |$)`, which kinda works on teststring 2, but fails to match `'two'`.

Is there any way I can do this with a regex, or should I split it into an array and then walk it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regex `( |^)\w+(?= |$)`

```
'one two three.four five six.seven eight'.replace(/( |^)\w+(?= |$)/g, '$1TEST')
```

Or without regex (maybe more readable)

```
'one two three.four five six.seven eight'.split(' ').map(function(item) {
    if(item.indexOf('.') < 0)
        return 'TEST';
    return item;
}).join(' ')
```

Comment: this is perfect! thanks! What exactly does the ?= do?

Comment: and your alternative solution while elegant is only working on IE9+.
To make it safe it would get more verbose, that's why I preferred the regex.

Comment: [Documentation for `(?=)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) _x(?=y) Matches x only if x is followed by y_. Also `.map` can work in IE8 if you use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill)

Answer (score 1):

Just get the matched characters by referring the group index 1.

```
(?:^| )([a-z]+(?= |$))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rI6jZ0/4)

```
> var re = /(?:^| )([a-z]+(?= |$))/g;
undefined
> var str = "one two three.four five six.seven eight";
undefined
> var matches = [];
undefined
> while (match = re.exec(str))
... matches.push(match[1]);
4
> console.log(matches);
[ 'one', 'two', 'five', 'eight' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use complex Regexp.
You can use splitting by space in conjunction with `Array.filter()` method:

```
var result = str.split(' ').filter(function(item) {
    return item.indexOf('.') < 0;
});
```

Comment: Thank You! But I actually need this for a replace, so I would have to rebuild the string afterwards. Of course you couldn't know, but that's why I am looking for a working RegEx. As I said at the end there's always the fallback of splitting and then walking the array.

Comment: @JanPaepke To rebuild, use `.join`

Comment: I know, thanks. :) As I said I was trying to find a solution without the detour of an array. But it seems like it's not possible...